# Visual Studio Intellisense does not provide the 'using namespace' option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I press `Ctrl+.` over any symbol in the editor, it has stopped showing me the option of inserting a `using` statement to include the namespace on the top of my file.

It just shows me the option to use the namespace qualified type name as depicted in the snapshot.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 RC. I have restarted it several times but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Use release version.

Comment: Just what I thought I'd hear. Will do when I get some more time. :-)